# architecture of input file `cppbblib.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output

Tags: c++, windows

soy nuevo en C++ y aún no entiendo muchas cosas.

Estoy tratando de resolver un algoritmo donde ya tiene una librería con funciones y el problema menciona que para compilar mi código necesito usar el comando:

```
g++ –o yourprogram cppbblib.o yourprogram.cpp
```

Pero al ejecutarlo em marca el error:

```
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `cppbblib.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
cppbblib.o: In function `ReceiveChar()':
cppbblib.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `_IO_getc'
cppbblib.o:(.eh_frame+0x11): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No entiendo lo que esta pasando, alguien podría explicarme por favor y también el como resolver este error, he buscado información pero no logro dar con la respuesta.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Y el `cppbblib.o` de donde lo sacas? Lo compilaste tu? De ser el caso, con que flags?